# integrate over the values in the first quadrant

Tags: plotting

With these formulas I get two slopes. `e` describes the energy. How can I integrate over the first quadrant for the values of `e`?

```
 w = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
 phi = ArcTan[x, y];
 a = 45*Pi/180;

j1[w_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[
Sqrt[Cos[t]] Sin[t]^2 BesselJ[1, (w Sin[t])/Sin[a]], {t, 0, 1}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 15]

e := 282.4*j1[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] Cos[ArcTan[x, y]];

ContourPlot[e, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

I thought about integrating over  `e` like this:

```
 NIntegrate[Abs[e]^2, {phi, 0, Pi/2}, PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
 MaxRecursion -> 15]
```

Why can't I just numerically integrate it?
    I also tried it with

```
Integrate[If[e < 10, 10, 0], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

and

```
Integrate[Boole[e < 10], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}].
```

Nothing worked. Another idea was to split the first quadrant of the plot into many little grids(each one has its own value for  `e`) and then sum each `e` up. Would that be doable?

Ideally I want to integrate over a unit circle.

Comment: Your numerical integrations depend on non-numerical parameters. For instance the expression for `j0` contains `w`, which depends on `x` and `y`. You may want to make `j0` explicitly a function of `x` and `y`, and restrict its evaluation to numerical values of those variables as well.

Comment: Also, `v` in `j0` and `j1` is never used. What is it for?

Comment: I corrected it. w is dependent of x and y, thats why I apply w to j0

Comment: sorry I mean j1

Answer (score 1):

First, remove what's unnecessary, and correct the typo `w` instead of `v` in the definition of `j1`:

```
a = 45*Pi/180.;
j1[v_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Sqrt[Cos[t]] Sin[t]^2 BesselJ[1, (v* Sin[t])/Sin[a]], {t, 0, 1}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 15]
e[x_,y_] := 282.4*j1[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] Cos[ArcTan[x, y]];
```

Then, everything works:

```
ContourPlot[e, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 5]
```

[image]

```
NIntegrate[Abs[e[x, y]]^2, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PrecisionGoal -> 2,
  MaxRecursion -> 15]
(* 4908.3 *)
```

To integrate on the unit circle simply parametrize x and y by theta in the following way:

```
NIntegrate[Abs[e[Cos[theta], Sin[theta]]]^2, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]
(* 2183.04 *)
```

Comment: thank you! And would it be possible to do it with the grids aswell?

Comment: @A.Opt I'm not sure what you mean by "grids": just changing the intergration bounds? To integrate on the unit circle, see the end of the edited answer.

Comment: for example to turn the ContourPlot in 'pixels' and each pixel with the same color has the same energy. Then just sum the pixels up.